# How to create bouncing div animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to re-create the bouncing arrow animation like on: http://www.codecomputerlove.com/ but it's not going well...

The closest I've got with trying to use the built in animations in Layerslider is available here: dev.themarketcreative dot com

I've decided that trying to figure this out with Layerslider is taking to long, does anyone know how to do this?

The furthest I discovered is this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/practice.cgi?file=jquery_149 but I need it do do this animation onload and on a continuous loop.

Thanks

Comment: please show us some code

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### **PURE CSS way to do this bounce**

Do like this.

```css
.bounce {
      position:fixed;
      left:50%;
      bottom:0;
      margin-top:-25px;
      margin-left:-25px;
      height:50px;
      width:50px;
      background:red;
      -webkit-animation:bounce 1s infinite;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes bounce {
      0%       { bottom:5px; }
      25%, 75% { bottom:15px; }
      50%      { bottom:20px; }
      100%     {bottom:0;}
    }
```

```html
<div class="bounce"></div>
```

Comment: Amazing, always love to use the CSS option. You star!

Comment: This css will work only for webkit browser. You need to add -moz-, -o-, -ms- to make it work on mozila, opera and ie 10 browser..

Comment: I should mention that codepen links to broken code. Just take a look at @RAJ answer below.  Should also note that an arrow without a shaft isn't really an arrow.  It's just an angle bracket.

Comment: @MiloLaMar Sorry.. Yes I was wrongly removed that link. If you want i'll ad a new one.

Comment: I actually saw one I found via google before arriving here. The inline example below still works so it shouldn't be necessary to add a new one.

Comment: Your key frames are really jerky, can just do ` 0%  { bottom: 0px; } 50%    {bottom: 20px;} 100% {bottom: 0px;}`

Answer (score 25):

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.arrow {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left:-20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-size: contain;
  
}

.bounce {
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}

/* Scroll down indicator (bouncing) */
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px); } }
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0); }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px); }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-15px); } }
@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0); }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px); }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px); } }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="arrow bounce">

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Nice inline Demo answer RAJ :)  Didn't know SO implemented this.

Comment: I keep making the boing sound when it bounces.  Nice solution!

Comment: I always like to know why things work, but it wasn't obvious to me from the implementation alone. Found a short keyframes animation [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0tClxmu_IQ) that helped break it down nicely.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it manually, frame-by-frame using `CSS` or you can probably automate it with `SCSS` with a bit of math and iteration.

```css
body{ overflow:hidden; } 

.ball{
  --size: 50px;
  --bounceHeight: 120px;
  --duration: .4s;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

/* bouncing */
.ball::before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 30% 20%, LightSalmon, transparent 40%), 
              radial-gradient(circle at -20% -30%, tomato 60%, darkred);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset;
  animation: bounce var(--duration) infinite alternate cubic-bezier(1,0,.8,.9); 
}

/* shadow */
.ball::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
  height: 20%;
  color: #CCC;
  background-color: currentColor;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(var(--bounceHeight)) scale(.8);
  animation: bounceShadow var(--duration) infinite alternate cubic-bezier(1,0,.8,.9); 
}

@keyframes bounce {
    85%  { transform: translateY(calc(var(--bounceHeight) - 3px)); }
    86%  { transform: translateY(calc(var(--bounceHeight) - 3px)) scale(1.1, .9); }
    100%  { transform: translateY(var(--bounceHeight)) scale(1.4, .5); }
}

@keyframes bounceShadow {
    0%  { box-shadow: 0 0 10px 8px currentColor; color:#EEE; }
    90%  { box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px currentColor; }
    91%  { box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px currentColor; }
    100%  { box-shadow: 0 0 0px currentColor; }
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```

[A much more elaborate demo can be seen here](https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/NWRPbQK)

Comment: This is incredible!

Answer (score 2):

You can use pure css to solve it.

```css
.image {
      margin-top: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: gold;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      animation: bounce 5s infinite alternate;
      -webkit-animation: bounce 5s infinite alternate;
    }
    @keyframes bounce {
      from {
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      to {
        transform: translateY(-55px);
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes image {
      from {
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      to {
        transform: translateY(-55px);
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <style>
      p {
           background-color:#bca;
           width:200px; 
           border:1px solid green; 
        }
     div{ width:100px; 
            height:100px; 
            background:red;  
        }
  </style>

<script src="http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>

<title>Birman Cats</title>
</head>

<body>

   <p>Click the button</p>
   <button id="button"> Bounce </button>

   <div class="target">
   </div>

<script>

   $(document).ready(function() {


         $(".target").effect( "bounce", 
          {times:3}, 300 );

         function bouncee(){

                $(".target").effect( "bounce",{times:3}, 300 );
   setTimeout(bouncee(),1000);
             }

     setTimeout(bouncee(),1000);


   });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the same code you provided, just replace the javascript with this js code.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {



      function doAnimation()
{
         $(".target").effect( "bounce", {times:3}, 300, doAnimation);
}

doAnimation();

   });
   </script>
```

Comment: Worked great but went for the CSS option. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
no
.trnas{
      margin-top: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: gold;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      animation: bounce 5s infinite alternate;
      -webkit-animation: bounce 5s infinite alternate;
    }
    @keyframes bounce {
      from {
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      to {
        transform: translateY(-55px);
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes image {
      from {
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      to {
        transform: translateY(-55px);
      }
    }
<div class="trnas"></div>
```

Comment: always provide a description for your answer and how it will solve the question.