# Page Transition Slide Down & Bounce

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click a button on my first webpage, I'd like to have the second page slide down and then bounce a few times. I've so far gotten a javascript function for the slide down action, but I can't figure out how to make the page then bounce. Is there a javascript bounce function? Should I use keyframes? If i use css keyframes, how do i relate them to my initial javascript function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

(function() {

    var windowH = $(window).height(),
        documElem = $(document),
        slideDownPage = $('.slide-down-page'),
        content = $('.content'),
        btns = $('.btn'),
        animSpeed = 500;

    slideDownPage.css({
        height: windowH + 'px',
        top: -windowH + 'px'
    });

  content.css({
  height: windowH+'px',})

    btns.on('click', function(e) {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('open') ) {
            slideDownPage.animate({'top': 0}, animSpeed);
            content.animate({'margin-top': windowH + 'px'}, animSpeed);
        }
        else {
            slideDownPage.animate({'top': -windowH + 'px'}, animSpeed);
            content.animate({'margin-top': 0}, animSpeed);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    documElem.on('scroll', function() {
        if ( $(this).scrollTop() > slideDownPage.height() && slideDownPage.css('top') === '0px' ) {
            slideDownPage.css('top', -windowH + 'px');
            content.css('margin-top', 0);
            documElem.scrollTop(0);
        }
    });         
})();      
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use css keyframs for this, an example taken from [How to create bouncing div animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23152900/how-to-create-bouncing-div-animation).

HTML:

```
<div class="bounce"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.bounce {
    -webkit-animation:bounce 1s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
      0%       { bottom:5px; }
      25%, 75% { bottom:15px; }
      50%      { bottom:20px; }
      100%     { bottom:0;}
}
```

Read more on css keyframes [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp).

Comment: thanks! how would you suggest i make the bounce occur after the page slides down? should i use animation delay? or is there a way to incorporate the css keyframes in my original javacript function?

Comment: You can use javascript / jQuery to add the class after the `slideToggle()` or whatever you use. @toniitony